# Hiding And Submitting A Form Using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Hide a form and submit that form using jquery?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

### On your HTML page:

```
<form id="my-form">
</form>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="submit">Submit</a>
```

### Your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#submit").click(function() {
    $("#my-form").hide(); 
    $("#my-form").submit();
  });
});
```

If your form contains a Submit button and you want the form to be hidden when the Submit button is pressed, instead you can listen to the submit event and handle it like this:

```
  $("#my-form").submit(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    return true;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Some scam?

You can place the form in a hidden div and using $(document).ready event, you can autosubmit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've added the jquery-ajax tag, I guess you want to submit the form through AJAX. In that case you are probably looking for something like this:

```
$("#your-form-id").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(){
       $("#your-form-id").hide();
    } 
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: I believe the order was the opposite: first hide, then submit. And I believe it should be hidden from the beginning, but I may be wrong in this case.

Comment: I think that code will submit the form twice, once with ajax and once without ajax.

Comment: @Tadeck It appears as if you were right, looking at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a field within a form that already has data inserted, eg. hard-coded in by you, the developer?

If this is the case, just set an id to the input field, with the value hard-coded in. Then set it's display to 'none'. Use your Jquery to interpret the data as normal.

You could also just make a variable in your jquery script, and avoid all this.